# Does anyone know/use MYSQL PDO with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have just read this [very nice] small tutorial about MYSQL error handling.
I am new to DB management, but I was just after something like that PDO he is mentioning over there.

Say I run a db sequential script, but instead of accessing the db straightforward, I'd use that PDO, does that mean that upon an exception being raised will I be able to simply rollback ?

It seems like magic to me, but then again, I am kinda noob, so I'd love to hear what you have to say about PDO.
Thanks !

Comment: Ted, your question is really vague. You should more specifically ask what you're interested in.

Comment: I think you are mixing up PDO and transactions.

Comment: I won't take offense by that. How am I being weird or silly? I am new to this field, and humbly ask for your help and knowledge. And, yes, I failed to include a link to that tutorial btw. http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die I also found all other answers quite helpful, Levi Hackwith. I really don't understand why I got -2. I guess I did something silly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit of a vague question, but for a good place to start learning how to do PDO with PHP and MySQL I'd start [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) with this nettuts article.

Answer (score 2):

> Say I run a db sequential script, but instead of accessing the db
>   straightforward, I'd use that PDO, does that mean that upon an
>   exception being raised will I be able to simply rollback

Only if the storage engine supports transactions (InnoDB does, MyISAM does not), and you are not in autocommit mode.

Comment: Well, I usually use phpMyAdmin to create my tables. I think I have a mixture of innoDB and MyISAM, should I switch to innoDB ? I have  heard it is a newer, yet not as yet proven and stable as MyISAM, engine. But I have no idea really. I am quite new to the field

Comment: if you have heard that its a 'newer, yet not as yet proven and stable', then you've heard something few years ago. InnoDB is already the default MySQL engine, it's stable, it have its supperiors already, and the only drawback is that InnoDB still does not support full-text indexing (it will in the next version of MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

If something goes wrong with your query in db PDOException is thrown. So you can use try ... catch block getting exception and process this situation correctly.